# Geometry: In the $\triangle ABC, AB=8, BC=7, CA=6$. Let $E$ be a point on $BC$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

In the $\triangle ABC, AB=8, BC=7, CA=6$. Let $E$ be a point on $BC$ such that $\angle BAE=3\angle EAC$. Find $\frac{4(AE)^2}{5}$.

In my solution I had started with the apollonius's theorem which pointed out to me $35.1$ as the answer. There are a few things I don't get -

- Can someone kindly try a solution with the angle relations?
- The answer key says $27$. Where could I have gone wrong?

P.S - I joined $AE$ since it was trivial and assumed it to be the median.

Comment: The conditions seem inconsistent to me.

Comment: $E$ cannot be the midpoint of $B$ if at the same time $∠=3∠$.

Answer (score 2):

CASE I: Point $E$ is between $B$ and $C$.

Let $AF$ be bisector of $\angle A$ then $\angle BAF=\angle CAF=2\alpha$

$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BF}{CF}$, $\frac{8}{6}=\frac{BF}{7-BF}$, then $BF=4$ and $CF=3$

$AF=\sqrt{AB\times AC - BF \times CF}=\sqrt{8\times 6 - 4\times 3}=6$

and

$\angle FAE=\angle CAE=\alpha$ then $AE\perp BC$

$AE^2 +FE^2=AF^2$ (Pythagorean theorem)

$AE^2=6^2-(\frac{3}{2})^2=\frac{135}{4}$

$\frac{4(AE)^2}{5}=27$

CASE II: Point $E$ is on side $C$

$\angle BAC=2\angle CAE = 2\alpha$

Let $AF$ be bisector of $\angle BA$C then $\angle BAF=\angle CAF=\alpha$

then

$BF=4$, $CF=3$ and $AF=6$

and $AC$ is the bisector of $\angle FAE$ and $\triangle ABF \cong \triangle AEC$ then $AE=8$

$\frac{4(AE)^2}{5}=\frac{256}{5}$

Comment: I think this is what the problem was intended to be - without the constraint of $E$ - midpoint of $BC$. Nice solution!

Comment: Done...Btw I considered point E on the side of B but in that case the triangle is not isosceles. What I'm saying is that the solution you gave is in accordance to the fact that AF=AC therefore bisector being perpendicular but since BAE is 3EAC shouldn't point E be closer to vertex B than C and in that case after applying stewart's the answer is different.

Comment: @The Revolution: Do you mean if the point $E$ is on side $C$.

Comment: Yes your solution is considering the isosceles triangle FAC where FA=AC=6 thus perpendicular is bisector but I'm curious why is the solution different if E is on triangle AFB in case of which it's different.

Comment: @The Revolution: I added for different positions of point $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions for the triangle are inconsistent: $\angle BAE=3\angle EAC$ is not only superfluous but in conflict with the previous conditions. The triangle is already uniquely determined by $AB=8, BC=7, CA=6$ and $E$ being the midpoint of $BC$.
[image]

Comment: So I guess there's a typo with the question. Btw thanks for the insight!

Comment: I think the question should have been E is a point (random) right? Because then I think we can solve it.

Comment: Yes, without the condition that $E$ is the midpoint it would be a solvable problem.

Comment: Can you help if the condition is non mid point? I tried mn cot theorem which gives three variables and 2 statements whereas cosine rule leaves 3x and x to be dealt with thus creating a cubic eqn. It would be helpful if I could notice atleast 2 approaches to this

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD$ be the bisector of $\angle BAC$. Then by the angle bisector theorem we get:
$$
BD=4,\quad CD=3.
$$
The length of bisector $AD$ can be computed by the formula:
$$
AD=\sqrt{AB\cdot AC- BD\cdot CD}=6.
$$
Hence $ACD$ is an isosceles triangle. The condition $∠=3∠$ means that $AE$ is the bisector of $\angle DAC$ (not the midpoint of $BC$) and it is thus easy to find the solution $AE=\sqrt{135}/2$.

[image]

Comment: how is it the bisector if its in the ratio 1:3?

Comment: @TheRevolution
$$∠={1\over2}∠={1\over4}∠={1\over3}∠B$$